# Javascript : Manipulating the status bar to display the date?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser, date, statusbar

I'm trying to write a script to display the current time on a page every minute on the status bar. However nothing shows up on the bar and I have no idea what is wrong.

```
        function display_time(){

            var d = new Date();
            var h = d.getHours(); // Extract hours
            var m = d.getMinutes(); // Extract minutes
            var ampm = (h >= 12)?"PM":"AM" // Convert to 12 hr format


            if (h > 12) h -= 12; // Next 4 lines; convert time to 12hr format
            if (h==0) h = 12; 
            if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
            var t = h + ':' + m + ' ' + ampm;
            defaultStatus = t;

            // Repeat function every minute
            setTimeout('display_time()', 60000);                         
        }
```

And Finally I call it as the page loads with `<body onload= 'display_time();'>`

The time however doesn't show in the status bar of any browser. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.status` instead of defaultStatus. But please be aware that you can't change the  status bar in some browsers.

Comment: Hmm I tried that, however it doesn't work in neither firefox nor Chrome. I'm still stumped as to why its like that...

Comment: See [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.status), i think it is the same for chrome